# Woocommerce - remove sale price field from dashboard

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Hello i use woocommerce and i want to remove the field from the admin panel. How can I do it right?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove the field using a code but you can disable using the sale price across the store.

**To disable sale price**

```
function custom_wc_get_sale_price( $sale_price, $product ) {
return $product->get_regular_price(); 
    return $sale_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sale_price', 'custom_wc_get_sale_price', 50, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_wc_get_sale_price', 50, 2 );
```

**To hide this field,** you can use a CSS to hide it from Product Edit screen. But that CSS needs to be loaded on the admin side, so putting this in theme style sheet may not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the CSS style to dashboard:

```
add_action('admin_head', function(){ ?>  
  <style>  #woocommerce-product-data ._sale_price_field {display:none;} </style> <?php 
});
```

put this code in `functions.php`